# Is it possible to add '-' flag in argparse of python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

Tools like dnsgen works with this both type of options:
Without any argument:
`cat domains.txt | dnsgen - | someotherprogram`
With argument:
`dnsgen -w wordlist filename.txt`

Can I make my program use `-` without argument i.e. `dnsgen -` style. Lets say my code is this and it can receive data from both stdin and wordlist

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-w', '--wordlist', help="Wordlist")
argv = parser.parse_args()
my_awesome_function(argv.wordlist)
```

So, my code reads only from wordlist. How can I make this both by wordlist and by stdin using `-` argument style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not an elegant solution but, You can assign a dummy variable and make it `store_true` as below.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-', "--_", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-w', '--wordlist', help="Wordlist")
argv = parser.parse_args()
my_awesome_function(argv.wordlist)
```